# CSS lost after postback only happens in IE Windows Phone

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am using this css for IE Windows Phone

`@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
   // css classes
  }`

This Media query don't have problem when first time page load, but if I trying to save a form or some post back event occure then this css has lost and apply another media query which is not for IE Browser.

Comment: Do you have a url we can hit?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this answer by using this media query. It's working after postback also.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px), screen\9 {
```

// css class

```
}
```